# Slow View Object in the Oracle ADF application?

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a 3 view object(vo1,vo2,vo3), all the three in the vo1-->vo2-->vo3 as the master detail relationship as vo1 is master of vo2 and vo2 is master of vo3 (vo1 and vo2 are connected by the primary key foreign key relationship). I am dynamically changing the where clause of the vo1, after changin the where clause during the execution of the vo1 the result set comes very quickly, but the vo2 takes long time for the execution,once after the vo1 where clause is changed dynamically. I couldn't figure out why it is taking so long time, due that performance of the application gets down. In the vo1 there are around 600 rows and in vo2 there are around 3000 rows. I am testing it through the weblogic server which is in the jdeveloper. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you traced the SQL and manually tried to run them to see how it performs ?
If not then that is first thing I would try. If it is just SQL being slow I would add some index next based on your SQL.

Some DB have tools like in Oracle SQL developer you can run SQL Tuning advisory or Explain Plan to tune your query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Amit,
When i run the SQL which the vo2 uses are executing at good speed in the SQL developer and indexed for the main columns, I have placed system.out.println() in the viewobject class, method createRowFromResultSet(), for finding the time it spends in that method, In the output in the console i could see that the rows fetched in few milliseconds but for printing the output in the console it takes time. Hope you could understand what i am trying to say. Thanks in advance.